# Image slider sporadically causing page wide black bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

Background: My company has a website built using "MojoPortal", which I believe is ASP. We used one of their apps to make a web banner/slider with six images. I'm told that in order for the built in app to work, images need to be in separate containers.

Issue: When the page loads we get a funky looking black bar where the image should be, the image size is drastically reduced and placed at the left side. This doesn't happen every time, seems to be better if images are cached on the machine, and goes away with a page refresh. So far this has occurred mostly on Chrome, but also on Firefox. Have not been able to recreate in edge.

I'm not much of a web developer. Wondering if this is rooted in the CSS or the built in "MojoPortal" application to slide the images. Seen this before?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBgQQ.png)

Editor:

```
<div><img alt="" src="img1" /></div>
<div><img alt="" src="img2" /></div>
<div><img alt="" src="img3" /></div>, etc
```

When viewing/inspecting page source:

```
element.style {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 6;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 720px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: [It looks like it is a nice feature](https://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=3351~-1)

Comment: Could you post generated html code for that?

Comment: Fire up your browser developer tools and inspect the element and its surrounding html.  The css classes applied to it will also be visible.  That's how I'd debug it.

Comment: This is all I have in the source block on the page editor. No class assigned, so maybe not a CSS issue unless the app is assigning a class. Could try to override.

<div><img alt="" src="img1" /></div>
<div><img alt="" src="img2" /></div>
<div><img alt="" src="img3" /></div>, etc -- when you inspect the page you get 


element.style {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 6;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 720px;
    height: 20px;
}